# What is the gross salary like for university engineering teachers in India?

Tags: salary, india

What is the gross salary like for **Assistant professor**s in India in publicly/privately funded universities in the area of engineering?

Comment: A valid question to ask them then.,..

Comment: As per the comment I made to your other similar question : the university most probably has a sliding scale based on experience plus many other factors so the best, and most effective, solution is to ask the university about the specific post... As the OP, You, have not provided the details of the specific post it is a question without an answer..

Comment: @SolarMike and other close voters: please see [this meta discussion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4269/20058).