# What is the gross salary like for university engineering professors in Pakistan?

Tags: career-path, salary

What is the gross salary like for **Assistant professor**s in Pakistan in publicly funded universities in the area of engineering?

Comment: @SolarMike maybe OP want to know expected salary before spending time to find a position in Pakistan.

Comment: @MBK then you should post the salary.... but if you don't know - ask the university...

Comment: @SolarMike did you understand my comment? People ask before moving any country. I was looking for position in Korea and I asked the question which helped me a lot. If you don't know the answer better let anyone to answer what OP asked.

Comment: So you did not understand - the university most probably has a sliding scale based on experience plus many other factors so the best, and most effective, solution is to ask the university about the specific post... As the OP has not provided the details of the specific post it is a question without an answer...

Comment: @MBK we can have the same discussion for this question : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/115512/72855

Comment: @SolarMike We certainly have questions about expected salaries in universities around the world: what makes this any different?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano how about the duplicate question for India?

Comment: @SolarMike India and Pakistan are not the same country and they don't have the same currency: how can you consider the two questions as duplicates? Would you consider them duplicates if they were about Belgium and France?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano it depends on how you wish to interperet the use of the word “duplicate” - I was not applying it to the country but, you obviously have.... I was applying it to the basis of the question...

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I still suggest the “best” option is ask the university as the salary offered will most likely be specific to a particular post.

Comment: @SolarMike As I asked you before: what makes these two questions any different with respect to the other questions we have (open) about salaries around the world? Why these two should be closed while the others are open?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Go ask the other voters to close...

Comment: I also think that both are perfectly appropriate questions with objective answers.

Comment: @SolarMike and other close voters: please see [this meta discussion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4269/20058).

Comment: if closing this question then must close all those questions asking for salary in US, UK, Korea, EU etc. I feel something fishy here. I never see such opposition for salary question but only for this question.

Comment: @SolarMike its not a discussion forum it is a Question Answer forum. How salary in india is related to salary in pakistan?

Comment: @MBK there are two separate questions, not one question asking for a comparison...